# Unable to save data from javascript to MySql using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xml

I have a problem that I unable to save data that are parsed from Javascript into PHP. The problem came when I implement WordPress. On single index.html it is working and data able to store in the database.

On Javascript file : *(send data)*

```
        var dbParam = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(dbParam);
        var obj, dbParam, xxmlhttp;
        xxmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xxmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xxmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/trackpage/dummy-data/saveDB.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
        xxmlhttp.send();
        console.log("send");
```

On PHP file: *(get data)*

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "laravelcrudwebapp");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tracks (data1,data2) VALUES (?, ?, )");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$obj->data1,$obj->data2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What is the output when you var_dump($obj); exit; ? Did you check it?

Comment: how to check the var_dump($obj) i try using echo to send data to test. Because i use wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to send your data as a GET parameter, you have to URL-encode it first:

```
var dbParam = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**However,** I will point out that **it is extremely bad practice to perform write operations via GET requests**. You're leaving yourself wide open for all sorts of abuse and cross-side scripting attacks. For starters, you can read this post, as well as do some research on Google:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server

Comment: this is the answer for the question. Thank you